# ElectronApp not sending cookie set up by backend

Tags: cookies, electron

I have a BackEnd which authenticates and sets up cookie for a domain like http://example.com, and I have an Electron app pointing to BE which successfully authenticates and sends back the cookie, after that, electron app sends requests to BE for further operations but the cookie is not being sent.